Selection of parent chain in a halogenated compound with double and triple bonds
We were asked to select the parent chain for naming the halogenated compound containing double and triple bonds:

My teacher told me that we choose the orange (1) one over the blue one (3) because as they have no functional groups, the same number of multiple bonds, the same number of side chains, we have to choose according to the alphabetical order. But in alphabetical order ‘e’ of ‘ene’ wins over ‘y’ of ‘yne’, hence orange one (1) wins.
Why aren't we choosing the green one (2), which has no functional groups, the same number of multiple bonds and three side chains, while others have just two?
Aren't Br and Cl side chain substituents?
And here my teacher has used a rule called “FMLSA”, according to which the priority of the factors is:

functional group;
number of multiple bonds;
number of carbons atoms (largest chain);
number of side chains;
alphabetical order.

Alphabetical order too involves using FMLSA in recursion.

Usual note: How to ask and answer nomenclature questions?

The IUPAC recommendations have been changed in 2013.  In the current version, the order of seniority between unsaturation and length of chain given in earlier recommendations is reversed. After finding a parent chain with the principal characteristic group, the first criterion to be considered is the length of the chain; unsaturation is now the second criterion.

But our textbooks in India still follow that old one. And I'm not sure which one would be followed in the examination I am preparing for

Lets call the most senior functional group the main group.
According to the IUPAC 2013 rules, the order is as follows (simplified for this example):

Number of occurrences of the main group. (P-44.1.1)
If it's cyclic it has seniority. (P-44.1.2.2)
Number of carbons atoms (largest chain)  (P-44.3.2);
Number of multiple bonds (P-44.4.1.1)
Number of double bonds (P-44.4.1.2)
Lowest set of locants for main group (P-44.4.1.8)
Lowest set of locants for ene/yne (P-44.4.1.10)
Maximum number of prefixes (P-45.2.1)
Lowest set of locants for prefixes (P-45.2.2)

So in this case (1) will win because it has the highest number of double bonds, which will result in the name (1E)-3-(bromoethynyl)-1-chloropenta-1,4-diene (1E because of the stereochemistry, the trans/E bond).
I added the numbers of the relevant sections of the "Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry. IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013."
These rules are for the Preferred IUPAC Name (PIN), other names are also acceptable.
